# Using LocalDateTime as @Version field with Hibernate 5.3 / JPA 2.2 on Java 11 leads to StaleObjectStateException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-time, optimistic-locking, staleobjectstateexception

Consider an entity called `Template` with a field:

```
@Version
@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATE", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime lastUpdate; // Java 8's class
```

The backing Oracle database field is `TIMESTAMP`.

Now executing the following code:

```
        // get EntityManager, start transaction
        final var t = new Template();
        t.setName("new template");
        t.setSubject("subject");

        em.persist(t);
        t.setSubject("subject - mod");
        tx.commit();
```

Causes an exception to be thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [Template#169]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2525)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3357)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3231)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3632)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1453)
... 59 common frames omitted
```

If I change the type of `lastUpdate` to `java.sql.Timestamp`, the code works properly. What could be the problem?

Although not stated exactly in the docs, i think Hibernate supports this type as @Version field.

A test case is available here: https://github.com/imeszaros/jooby-hbm-localdatetime

Comment: I have tested the code that you have shown, but no exception is thrown. here is the [github repo](https://github.com/ahenteti/stackoverflow/blob/master/jpa-version-annotation/src/main/java/io/github/ahenteti/java) I have used to checkout your problem. Could you please check what I'm missing and what you can show more to help us helps you

Comment: @A.Henteti I forget to mention that we're using Java 11. Please check out the following repo: https://github.com/imeszaros/jooby-hbm-localdatetime

In `App.java` there is an SQL script for the database table. Just try to launch the app, it should lead to the mentioned exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record: Oracle's `TIMESTAMP` type has a precision of 6 by default, which can only store milliseconds.

Java's `LocalDateTime` however may have nanoseconds, therefore you need to use `TIMESTAMP(9)` in the database to be able to store the values without the loss of precision.